# Datatable with a nested table inside every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I've been trying to do an HTML document that uses a datatable with every row containing an inside row with an another table detailing more info about the row, but I've been running into issues with the formatting and the functionality of the inside row (it just keeps stuck in the left side with out styling).

```js
/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
  var sOut = '<table>';
  sOut += '<thead> <tr> <th>Factura</th> <th>Fecha</th> <th>Dias</th> <th>Monto</th> <th>Pendiente</th> <th>Vendedor</th> </tr></thead>';
  sOut += '<tbody> <tr> <td>Factura</td> <td>Factura</td> <td>Factura</td> <td>Factura</td> <td>Factura</td> <td>Factura</td> </tr> </tbody> ';
  sOut += '</table>';

  return sOut;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
   * Insert a 'details' column to the table
   */
  var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
  var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
  nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="../examples_support/details_open.png">';
  nCloneTd.className = "center";

  $('#example thead tr').each(function() {
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
  });

  $('#example tbody tr').each(function() {
    this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
  });

  /*
   * Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
   */
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "bSortable": false,
      "aTargets": [0]
    }],
    "aaSorting": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });

  /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
   * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
   * rather it is done here
   */
  $('#example tbody td img').on('click', function() {
    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
      /* This row is already open - close it */
      this.src = "./resources/details_open.png";
      oTable.fnClose(nTr);
    } else {
      /* Open this row */
      this.src = "./resources/details_close.png";
      oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
#page {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #959595;
  font: normal 12px/2.0em Sans-Serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: darkblue;
  text-align: center;
}
#page {
  background: #fff;
}
#header,
#footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#logo {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
#header {
  background: #fff;
}
#header-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#footerblurb {
  background: #d3d3f9;
  color: blue;
}
#footer {
  background: #fff;
}
#footer-inner {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}
#footer a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#events {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
td.highlight {
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
}
.details-control {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.slider {
  display: none;
}
table.dataTable tbody td.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
.bodycontainer {
  max-height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#col-lg-6 {
  margin: auto;
}
#formulario {
  margin: auto;
  column-width: 80%;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <title>Consulta de facturas atrasadas</title>
</head>

<body>

  <br>
  <div id="page">
    <header id="header">
      <div id="header-inner">
        <div id="logo">
          <h1></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <br>


    <table id="example" class="row-border hover order-column display" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Propietario</th>
          <th>Direccion</th>
          <th>Ciudad</th>
          <th>Sector</th>
          <th>Cedula</th>
          <th>Tel. 1</th>
          <th>Tel. 2</th>
          <th>Celular</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>

          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Propietario</th>
          <th>Direccion</th>
          <th>Ciudad</th>
          <th>Sector</th>
          <th>Cedula</th>
          <th>Tel. 1</th>
          <th>Tel. 2</th>
          <th>Celular</th>

        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Propietario</td>
          <td>Direccion</td>
          <td>Ciudad</td>
          <td>Sector</td>
          <td>Cedula</td>
          <td>Tel. 1</td>
          <td>Tel. 2</td>
          <td>Celular</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Propietario</td>
          <td>Direccion</td>
          <td>Ciudad</td>
          <td>Sector</td>
          <td>Cedula</td>
          <td>Tel. 1</td>
          <td>Tel. 2</td>
          <td>Celular</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Propietario</td>
          <td>Direccion</td>
          <td>Ciudad</td>
          <td>Sector</td>
          <td>Cedula</td>
          <td>Tel. 1</td>
          <td>Tel. 2</td>
          <td>Celular</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Propietario</td>
          <td>Direccion</td>
          <td>Ciudad</td>
          <td>Sector</td>
          <td>Cedula</td>
          <td>Tel. 1</td>
          <td>Tel. 2</td>
          <td>Celular</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Codigo</td>
          <td>Nombre</td>
          <td>Propietario</td>
          <td>Direccion</td>
          <td>Ciudad</td>
          <td>Sector</td>
          <td>Cedula</td>
          <td>Tel. 1</td>
          <td>Tel. 2</td>
          <td>Celular</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>


    </table>





    <div class="clr"></div>

    <div id="footerblurb">
      <br>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer">

      <div id="footer-inner">
        <p></p>
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a class to the inside table when you create the element like `insideTable`:

```
function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
  var sOut = '<table class="insideTable">';
  // ... the other lines
}
```

And in your css, you can style this inside table:

```
.insideTable {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Is this what you were trying to achieve ? [Here is a demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LHXWKdh3q8CoP40AlVXT?p=preview).

**Edit**

After adding the class to the table you can style each element inside like:

```
.insideTable tbody {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so soon! There are a few thing that i still would like to achieve: the <tfoot> doesnt cover the same distance as the <thead>, how could i edit the search and outside features of the datatable so that it covers the same width as the main table and also would like to know if i could do a MAGIC software connection using the <MGREPEAT> on the main table and the details table. Thanks again for your attention.

Comment: I updated the answer for more inside table styling. If you have other questions you should  update your initial question or create a new one

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez don't forget to mark the answer as 'accepted' if it solved your problem. Just click the tick mark below the score for the answer.